# Установка Windows 7 на ssd

Tags: windows

при установке окошек всплывает окно **Не найден необходимый драйвер для дисковода оптических дисков**

Недавно был куплен ноутбук hp hq tre 71025 На нем стояла штатная 10ка 
было принято решение заменить dvd rom на ssd kingston 120 gb и установить на него  windows 7

принятые шаги

1. установка легаси мода в биосе
2. установка чистого образа (не сборки) windows 7 на флешку
3. были перепробованы 3 разных флешки включая одну cd карту 
   с каждой удалось загрузиться и дойти до вышеописанной ошибки,

какие драйвера он просит если в ноутбуке нет dvd rom ??  и как решить данную проблему

Comment: Попробуйте использовать данный метод. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRykHuCPdlc

Comment: Попробуйте отключить в биосе поддержку USB 3.0 и устанавливать систему с флешек USB 2.0. Ну и процентов 99%, что с внешнего сидирома система встанет.

Comment: @IgorSergeevich, нет, это не код! https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/178988

Comment: @Igor вы используете форматирование внутристрочным кодом не по назначению. [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй HDD и SSD местами. Иногда бывает, что всякие DVD и прочая второстепенная периферия подключена через другой контроллер. Т.е. на месте винта будет кингстон, а на месте привода будет родной бучный винт.

Comment: данное решение не помогло

Comment: Хм. Я бы посоветовал поставить винду по сети, но это надо инфраструктуру поднимать. А что, если выкрутить винт, накатить туда на другом компе\ноуте только винду без дров и прочего (но установщики всё-же запихнуть) и собрать как было?

Comment: установка по сети прошла успешно

Comment: @baneling, о, а на чём именно сетевую установку поднимал?

Comment: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_ubuntu_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8 вот так только образ использовал семерки

Comment: @baneling, это типа как "ну для установки я юзал tcp, ip, udp и ещё RJ-45 aka 8p8c". Я в курсе что такое установка по сети - на работе около тысячи инсталляций именно windows. Мне интересна конкретная реализация.

Comment: не понимаю что вы имеете под конкретной реализацией, все делал по статье ссылку оставил выше, из железа использовал 2 ноутбука, одни с ubuntu 16.04 на второй устанавливал  виндовс 7 между ними проводок витая пара

Comment: @baneling, т.е. seed-файл с ответами подходит для установки windows?

Answer (score 1):

В дистрибутиве Windows 7 нет драйверов для вашего SSD, видимо, поэтому он ошибочно воспринимается как оптический привод.

Вам нужно найти драйвер и подсунуть его программе установки. Как это сделать - легко гуглится, но я уже нагуглил это за вас :)

[ТЫЦ](http://remontka.pro/no-hdd-on-windows-7-8-setup/)

Comment: ссылки на внешние ресурсы не приветствуются, лучше всего указать самое главное в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

**Битый repack, my friend.**

А еще лучше оригинальный образ с офф сайта малокософта скачайте дистрибутив Вин10, бесплатно же.

*А вот кряк это уже другая проблема, но уже не такая серьезная как установка ОС.*

Comment: О каком кряке речь, если изначально стояла лиц win10?

Answer (score -1):

Помнится, помнится такая ерундистика была, дело в том, что это кривой пак винды.
Скачайте нормальный пак и не парьтесь.
Дальше если у вас ранее не стоял SSD - обязательно выставите режим AHCI в BIOS, иначе время от времени, комп будет перезагружаться или выключаться со сбоем, не допустите этого.
Далее обновите все драйвера ATA / ATAPI, для более лучших результатов работы SSD диска.